# How can I ping a user for chat?

Tags: support, chat, notifications, ping

Say I'm in a chat room, and the person I am trying to reach isn't there. I want to ping him/her and sort of invite him/her to the conversation. So essentially whenever that person gets logged into the Stack Exchange network he/she should get a ping notification in his/her inbox.

Is this possible or not actually possible at the moment?

Comment: Gosh, I hope not.. IIRC, you can ping users that have been in the chat room recently enough, but not users that have never been there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters why "gosh, I hope not".  If it couldn't be done from there then it could be done in a comment, so it's not like "oh no the world has come to an end, / this is a negative thing, you can ping somebody from chat" 'cos you can ping somebody from comment too. it's not like it's more open to abuse if it is done in chat. It's just a feature that is lacking, and there's nothing negative were that feature to be added. At present if one wants to notify somebody about a chat, and their name isn't coming up with the @ in the chat, they have to do it in a comment

Comment: Just want to address the misinformation in the Aug. 12 comment above this one: no, you cannot ping anyone you like in the comments. There are [specific rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/1017231) to make sure you can only notify people who have some activity with the relevant post.

Answer (score 4):

You can @notify users that recently were in this specific chat room. You can also go to their profile and choose the "start a new room with this user" button to create a new room and invite them. Both methods will result in a notification for the target user.

They won't work for a user that doesn't have a chat account, only moderators can ping such users.